# By continuity, the upper and lower contour sets of a bundle are closed

Tags: microeconomics

Mas-Collel, Winston and Green's Microeconomic Theory (3rd edition), states that the continuity of a preference relation implies the upper and lower contour sets of a bundle are closed. I would like to know why.

[image]

Definition of continuous preference relation:

[image]

Definition of open set:

[image]

Definition of closed set:

[image]